# sorting a list with objects of a class as its items

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

i have a python list whose items are objects of a class with various attributes such as birthday_score, anniversary_score , baby_score..... I want to to sort the list on the basis of one of these attributes ,say anniversary_score. How do i do it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
your_list.sort(key = lambda x : x.anniversary_score)
```

or if the attribute name is a string then you can use :

```
import operator
your_list.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('anniversary_score'))
```

Comment: `your_list.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('anniversary_score'))`

Answer (score 5):

`attrgetter` is handy if you don't know the name of the attribute in advance (eg. maybe it is from a file or a function parameter)

```
from operator import attrgetter

sorted(my_list, key=attrgetter('anniversary_score'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sorted`:

```
class X():
     def __init__(self, a_s):
          self.anniversary_score = a_s

li = [X(1), X(2), X(3), X(4)]
sorted(li, key=lambda x: x.anniversary_score)
```

Generally, the [Python Sorting Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) has just about everything you'll ever need to know about sorting in Python.

Comment: You should really use ``attrgetter`` as shown in the wiki page you linked.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to define in your class the `__lt__()` and `__eq__()`methods, which will tell Python how one instance of your class should be sorted when compared to another:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sortattr = 'anniversary_score' # you can use 'baby_score', 'birthday_score' instead
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return getattr(self, self.sortattr) < getattr(other, other.sortattr)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return getattr(self, self.sortattr) == getattr(other, other.sortattr)
```

Then, just use `sort()` as you do for a list of numbers, strings etc:

```
 mylist.sort() # to sort in-place

 sorted(mylist)  # to return a new sorted list
```

Comment: `cmp` is dead, use `key` instead

Comment: @jamylak I've updated the answer! Thank you for the feedback, I read that for Python 3.0 one should use `__lt__()` or `__eq__()` since `__cmd__()` is no longer supported.